# How to use Degrees System in Python3

Tags: python, math

Am going to program that use Some Angles .. By using Py3 
How to make Python use Degrees System instead of Radian ..
I've Tried to :

```
A=cos(22)
A=degrees(A)
print (A)
and the output is not Equaling 0.92718
```

Comment: Did you mean Radian ?

Comment: `math.radians(360)` will give you approximately 2*pi

Comment: Note that the result of computing `cos(22)` is a dimensionless number, not a measure of degrees.  Your code seems confused on this point.

Comment: I think this is a bit of an x-y problem.. python doesn't "use" degrees you just need to edit your math to convert wherever relevant. You will find it hard to find anything other than a handheld calculator that will return results from trig functions in or from degrees. this is largely because the conversion is easy, and the behind-the-scenes way trig functions are actually calculated ([Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)) use radians

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might as well know about the **numpy** library. You can make what you want to do very explicit.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.cos(np.deg2rad(22))
0.92718385456678742
```

Comment: Thank you Very much <3 !

Answer (score 1):

Python includes casting functions for radians and degrees

```
A = math.cos(math.radians(22))
```

Comment: I've tried This before ... and it's still wrong , my calculator says that the answer is 0.9271 ..

is The output , of A=cos(22) is in radians ?
if it is .. Can i Convert it using math.degrees() , i mean is it correct ?

Comment: I just tried this and I got 0.9271... as result. The cos function is expecting radians not degrees so you need to cast the 22 "degrees" before.